# Is there a faster way to loop through thousands of items?

Tags: c#, loops, arrays

Say I have a byte array with 100,000 bytes in it. I want to convert each byte into its textual representation of itself. For example:

```
byte[] b = new byte[55000];

for(int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToString(b[i]));
}
```

The above code takes around 35 seconds to complete, is there some way I could cut that down to around 5 seconds?

Comment: have you tried using something other than `Console.WriteLine()` or dropping it entirely and then testing the time requirement? Even if it is just using a stringbuilder and then outputting the stringbuilder string after all of the loops have completed it should help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment I would suggest removing the `Console.WriteLine()` method. I would also suggest that it be avoided in loops. Typically if you want to see what is being processed you would use either the `Debug.WriteLine()` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx)) or set a breakpoint (even a conditional breakpoint if you have a specific case that isn't working right). If you need to return the data then again i would suggest using a string builder:

```
byte[] b = new byte[55000];
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
    myStringBuilder.AppendLine(ConvertToString(b[i]));
}
Console.Write(myStringBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Using your suggestions, I got this to work in **under** the requested 5 seconds - awesome job, thank you, Gary.

Answer (score 3):

one thing I fond is Write a [Parallel.For Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460703.aspx) with might do faster thing than right now..

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] nums = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).ToArray();
        long total = 0;

        // Use type parameter to make subtotal a long, not an int
        Parallel.For<long>(0, nums.Length, () => 0, (j, loop, subtotal) =>
        {
            subtotal += nums[j];
            return subtotal;
        },
            (x) => Interlocked.Add(ref total, x)
        );

        Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}", total);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the order will be changed when using parallel methods. `.AsOrdered()` may be able to help however will incur a performance penalty.

Comment: In this case, order is very important for what I'm doing. Console.WriteLine() is going to be replaced by some other function.

Answer (score -1):

Profile your code to see what method is taking the most time.  Focus your optimization efforts on that method.