# Is there a way to use Parallel processing to read chunks from a file and join together the string in order?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, stream, stringbuilder

I see many examples on how to add numbers using Parallel, however I have not found anything that could demonstrate reading in multiple chunks (say 512 bytes per chunk) in parallel from a stream, and have the results joined together.

I would like to know if it is possible to read multiple parts of a stream and have them concatenated together in proper order.

### For example

Assume the following text file

```
Bird
Cats
Dogs
```

And reading in a chunk size of 5 bytes, from a normal stream would be something like :

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
int bytesRead = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using (Stream stream = new FileStream( "animals.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read )) {
    while ( (bytesRead = stream.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length )) > 0 ) {
        sb.Append( Encoding.UTF8.GetString( buffer ) );
    }
}
```

Would read in each line (all lines are 5 bytes) and join them together in order so the resulting string would be identical to the file.

However, consider using something like [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9155968/3504007) seems like it would potentially join them out of order.  I also don't know how it would apply in the above context to replace the `where` loop.

How can I read in those chunks simultaneously and have them append to `StringBuilder` the bytes from each iteration - not the order the iteration occurs, but the order which is proper so I don't end up with something like

```
Cats
Bird
Dog
```

Sorry I don't have any parallel code to show as this is the reason for the post. It seems easy if you want to sum up numbers, but to have it work in the manner that it is as follows :

- Reading from a stream in byte chunks (say 512 bytes per chunk)
- Appending to a master result in the order which they are in the stream, not necessarily the order processed.

... seems to be a daunting challenge

Comment: A stream is inherently a sequential structure on which you cannot operate with parallel operations. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)): “In computer science, a stream is a sequence of data elements made available over time.”

Comment: @Renzo - thank you for that.  The objective is essetially from a `byte[]` array reading X number of bytes at a time from it.   I apologize that the sample code doesn't fully illustrate this as I can't think of a better way to illustrate the logic inside the looping mechanism or to show what my intent is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By their nature, streams are not compatible with parallel processing.  The abstraction of a stream is sequential access.

You can read the stream content sequentially into an array, then launch parallel processing on it, which has the desired effect (processing is parallelized).  You can even spawn the parallel tasks as chunks of the stream arrive.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
do {
   var buffer = new byte[blockSize];
   var location = stream.Position;
   stream.Read(buffer);
   tasks.Add(ProcessAsync(buffer, location)); 
} while (!end of stream);
await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Or, if you have random access, you can spawn parallel tasks each with instructions to read from a particular portion of the input, process it, and store to the corresponding part of the result.  But note that although random access to files is possible, the access still has to go through a single disk controller... and that hard disks are not random access even though they expose a random-access interface, non-sequential read patterns will result in a lot of time wasted seeking, lowering efficiency far below what you get from streaming.  (SSDs don't seek so there's not much penalty for random request patterns, but you don't benefit either)

---

Thanks to @Kraang for collaborating on the following example, matching the case of parallel processing binary data.

If reading from bytes alone, you could use parallel processing to handle the chunks as follows :

```
// the byte array goes here
byte[] data = new byte[N];

// the block size
int blockSize = 5;

// find how many chunks there are
int blockCount = 1 + (data.Length - 1) / blockSize;

byte[][] processedChunks = new byte[blockCount][];
Parallel.For( 0, blockCount, ( i ) => {
    var offset = i * blockSize;

    // set the buffer size to block size or remaining bytes whichever is smaller
    var buffer = new byte[Math.Min( blockSize, data.Length - offset )];

    // copy the bytes from data to the buffer
    Buffer.BlockCopy( data, i * blockSize, buffer, 0, buffer.Length );

    // store buffer results into array in position `i` preserving order
    processedChunks[i] = Process(buffer);
} );

// recombine chunks using e.g. LINQ SelectMany
```

Comment: the stream is actually a memorystream of bytes, not from a file.  i was using that data as an example. i do not want to read sequentially.  the idea is to read multiple at the same time (in parallel)

Comment: @KraangPrime: That's why I mentioned the random-access option, because not all streams are serialized through a disk.  But since your MemoryStream actually is an array to begin with, why not just give the tasks slices of that array? (there's an ArraySegment class that describes an array slice)

Comment: essentially, this is what i am trying to improve the performance of by decrypting multiple blocks at the same time >  [Code Review: Public key chunked encryption with C# method to decrypt](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151376/public-key-chunked-encryption-with-c-method-to-decrypt/151377#151377)

Comment: @KraangPrime: depending on the block chaining scheme of your cipher, each block may depend on the decoded plaintext from the block ahead of it.  Are you using [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) or [CFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Feedback_.28CFB.29)?

Comment: Nope, i am using public key encryption, private key decryption.  Pretty hard code.  Since it doesn't support chunks larger than the byte size of the key (eg 4096 key = 512 bytes), the data must be encrypted in chunks (see the php portion), and hence, must be decrypted in chunks.  The problem is doing this sequentially is slower than I would like. (about 3 seconds for the sample posted on code review)

Comment: The only real option I can think of, is to decrypt multiple blocks at the same time in parallel somehow -- hence the question.   I really do have a good reason for this, and explained as best I could trying to keep the problem I am trying to solve separate from the rest of the code. Consider the problem as is here --  read multiple chunks from a byte array simultaneously and put them back together in their proper order.

Comment: @KraangPrime: I left a comment on the other site explaining how your approach differs from the usual technique.  Poor performance is expected from asymmetric decryption.  Anyway, if you persist in doing it the bad way, it can still be parallelized.  Just get rid of the useless `MemoryStream` and use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to break the big array into individual buffers.  If each subtask remembers where in the input its buffer was copied from, it can copy its result to that spot in the output.

Comment: @KraangPrime: it's really simple, just `Parallel.For(0, encryptedBytes.Length / 512, (int i) => { Buffer.BlockCopy(encryptedBytes, i * 512, 512, buffer = new byte[512], 0); Buffer.BlockCopy(rsa.Decrypt(buffer), 0, 512, decryptedResult, i * 512); });`.

Comment: Could you be so kind as to provide an example (obviously this method would eliminate stream from the equation. That was an answer to a subpart of my question I was previously unaware of) -  I think `Events.AsParallel().AsOrdered()` seems to be part of what I am looking for for maintaining an order on return. I have never worked with `.AsParallel()` before, and the examples I have seen thus far are over-simplistic like adding numbers together or joining random words in no particular order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132000/discussion-between-kraang-prime-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: Thank you for your help with this.  I have updated your solution with what we figured out together, upvoted and accepted as solution.  May this help many happy campers in the future :)